# store returned value of the function in a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

Problem I'm having is that I have this function that creates the random digit number :

```
    //user_length() has a value of a favored length of number entered by user
    //random_digit() returns digit randomly from 1-9



    function random_number(){
          let sequence = [];
          for(i = 0; i < user_length() ; i++ ){
             sequence.push(random_digit());
          }

          return sequence.toString().replace(/,/g,"")
        }
```

but I have to call this function twice in different places:

```
//to chack wether what user has written matches the displayed nuber or not
function check(){
    
    let inputVal = document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    let original_val = num_length();
    for (i = 0 ; i < user_length() ; i++){
      return inputVal[i] === original_val[i] ? console.log(num_length()) : console.log(inputVal + " is wrong,right answer is " + num_length())
    }

   
  }

//to display number on screen for user to "remember"
function number_onScreen(){
    create_p();
    let random_num= document.getElementById("random_number");
    random_num.innerHTML = num_length();
    random_num.style.margin = "0px";
    random_num.style.padding = "0px";
    
  }
```

what happens is that number that is displayed on the screen is different from the number Check() function compares to the one user tried to remember. for example, the displayed number was: 23749

the user would also write 23749 if they remembered correctly, but the check() function has a different value from the displayed number and the user will never guess that. I understand that my problem is that I call the random_number() function two different times and that's why they have different value, I tried to store the output in the variable but don't really know how to so I always got "Undefined " as an output, what do I have to change ?

Comment: If you `return` from a loop, you only run the first item.

Comment: sorry could you explain little better ?

Comment: [return](https://www.php.net/return) "If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function [...] If return is called from within the main script file, then script execution ends." `for (i = 0 ; i < user_length() ; i++)` ends the first time you enter it.